# HTC Desire HD unlocked, cannot connect to 3G

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, htc-desire, connection-issues, 3g

I recently bought an unlocked AT&T HTC Desire HD from an E-bay seller in India.
I'm using a Tata Docomo Sim on the device. Although having subscribed to 3G data, I am not able to use it. Can anyone help me with how I can configure and use 3G with my mobile?

I tried all the APN settings available online, of which none worked. I am able to just use the EDGE (2G) network, which is too slow. Hope someone helps me to connect 3G on HTC Desire HD for Tata DoCoMo India.

Regards,
Praveen

Comment: As you are able to use 2G, your APN settings are probably correct (though you might contact your provider to make sure of that). Could it be the area where you are located is lacking 3G coverage? Can you use 3G with other devices there (cross-check)? Then there's always the possibility that you've got a crippled device -- unless it suddenly works with a different SIM card (again, cross-check).

Comment: no one here using 3G.. will try to check. Is there any posibilty to check weather my phone's is good or not ?

Comment: If you have another device with working 3G and can use its SIM in your phone, this should be a good indicator. Apart from that (and a repair center), I have no further idea how to check. Maybe a look into the system logs gives a clue, and maybe the "test menues" (look for "secret codes": `*#4646#*` should lead to a field test on some phones, e.g.) might hold something.

Comment: @praveenkumar Where do you live in India? Tata DoCoMo don't have a wide 3G network. They don't have 3G even in cities like Mumbai!! Make sure they have 3G coverage is your area. You can try putting that SIM in other phone.

Comment: I consulted with Service center, I'm in Mysore. They said not to use DoCoMo.. M switching to vodafone.

Answer (score 1):

AT&T uses 3G frequency bands 850 MHz and 1900 MHz.  From what I can tell from the phones they sell, Tata Docomo uses the 900 MHz and 2100 MHz 3G bands.  They're not intercompatible.  Most often when you buy a US phone for use outside the country you'll want the T-Mobile version. Or a quad-band or 5-band phone which would eliminate the problem altogether.

Comment: Yes, the phone is Quadband. Its because of the network problem. Thank you :)

Comment: Not according to any spec sheet I've seen ([e.g.](http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_desire_hd-3468.php)) but if it works on Vodafone then great!

Comment: Hope it will works with Vodafone :)